# Контролирование нескольких инпутов в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть задача: надо сделать, к примеру, 4 инпута, так что в них можно внести только целые положительные числа с 0 до 64. Я уже голову сломала над тем, как это правильно сделать, прошу о помощи.

Код:

```js
const {useState} = React;

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState([{
      id: 1,
      value: 0
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      value: 0
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      value: 0
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      value: 0
    }
  ]);
  
  console.log(value);

  function Validate(e) {
    console.log(Number(e.target.name), Number(e.target.name));
    
    if (Number(e.target.value) > 64) {
      setValue([{
        id: Number(e.target.name),
        value: 64
      }]);
    } else if (Number(e.target.value) < 64) {
      setValue([{
        id: Number(e.target.name),
        value: Number(e.target.value)
      }]);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      
      <div>
        <input
          value = {value[0].value}
          name = {1}
          onChange = {(e) => Validate(e)}
        />
        <input
          value = {value[1].value}
          name = {2}
          onChange = {(e) => Validate(e)}
        />
        <input
          value = {value[2].value}
          name = {3}
          onChange = {(e) => Validate(e)}
        />
        <input
          value = {value[3].value}
          name = {4}
          onChange = {(e) => Validate(e)}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

P.S. Пытаюсь решить через один стейт, через 4 стейта всё понятно.

Comment: Пожалуйста перенесите ваш код сюда по [инструкции](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12004/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%a4%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-stack-snippet-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-react-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-jsx)

Comment: Явно не переносился код по [инструкции](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12004/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%a4%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-stack-snippet-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-react-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-jsx) :)

Comment: @EzioMercer, что-то не получается верно перенести код =\

Comment: Что именно не получается? Там в конце есть много примеров для разных ситуаций

Comment: @EzioMercer, вот такая ошибка Error:{
  "message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "",
  "lineno": 0,
  "colno": 0
}

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что пока я не увижу ваш код тут и не смогу запустить, я не смогу понять к чему именно относится ваша ошибка :)

Comment: Нельзя пользоваться импортами, они не работают. В примерах указано как заменить импорт на деструктуризацию. И не нажимайте эту кнопку "Привести в порядок" он отвратительно форматирует jsx

Comment: Поправил ваш код, можете принять изменения, теперь он будет запускаться без ошибок. Кроме импорта нельзя ещё использовать синтаксис типа `obj?.property`. Такс с этим кодом, теперь можно порабоать)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такс у вас было сразу несколько ошибок:

- Вы перепутали `e.target.value` и `e.target.name`
- Как `name` так и `value` надо было приводить к числому виду, чтобы сравнивать корректно
- Вы полностью перезаписывали старый стейт, массивом из всего 1-ого элемента. Я показал как надо правильно менять состояние. Очень важно сначала скопировать старые состояние чтобы его случайно не мутировать. Работаем с его копией и потому уже после всех необходимых действий вставляем изменённую копию как новый стейт
- У вас не было обработки случая, когда `value === 64`

Это было не ошибкой, но писать `(e) => Validate(e)` лишнее нагромождение кода, т.к. если никаких специальных аргументов вы не отправляете, то все аргуметы автоматически отправятся в нужную вам ф-ию

```js
const {useState} = React;

const App = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState([{
      id: 1,
      value: 0
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      value: 0
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      value: 0
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      value: 0
    }
  ]);

  const validate = (e) => {
    const value = Number(e.target.value);
    const nameAsNum = Number(e.target.name);
    const prevState = [...values];
    
    prevState.find(item => item.id === nameAsNum).value = value >= 64 ? 64 : value
    
    setValues(prevState);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      
      <div>
        <input
          value = {values[0].value}
          name = {1}
          onChange = {validate}
        />
        <input
          value = {values[1].value}
          name = {2}
          onChange = {validate}
        />
        <input
          value = {values[2].value}
          name = {3}
          onChange = {validate}
        />
        <input
          value = {values[3].value}
          name = {4}
          onChange = {validate}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```